# jQuery Flexigrid set fixed height

Tags: jquery, flexigrid

It seems that even if I set the height for a Flexigrid, it still allows the user to alter the grid's height by dragging. How can I disable this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resorted to manipulating the Flexigrid code. It's a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Add `resizable: false` to the properties when creating the flexigrid.